# Generting *.txt file in command prompt works but not in *.bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to get all users at my client to get hteir PC MAC addresses by runnning an `ipconfig /all` command. I tested this on my PC with Command Prompt and it works, but a soon as I write this as a batch file it does not output the *.txt file. Where am I going wrong?

```
ipconfig /all > "Desktop/UserIP.txt"
```

Comment: do you have anything apart from the command in your bat file? this command worked for me from bat file as well.

Comment: Is your script running in the right directory? Also, if you're running the script as Administrator, it will start in System32 instead of the current directory, so also look there.

Comment: Specify an absolute path to the text file rather than a relative one. And the Windows path separator is `\ `but not `/`…

Comment: @Kundan The code at the end is the only code in the .bat file so I am not sure what else to do. SomethingDark This is just a normal user-level execution, not elevated.

Comment: @aschipfl no luck. So waht I need to do is collect all user's MAC address to register them on the Firewall but they still have generic PC names so its not clear who is who. So I want to send them a .bat they can run and then email me the .txt file and I can register them. But the .bat part is not doing what is intended

Comment: Try ipconfig /all > "UserIP.txt" and see if the text file is generated in the same location where the bat file is stored

Comment: @Kundan thanks that works. Will just tell them to copy do desktop and then run command.

Comment: There is no way that somebody would need to send batch files to everyone on the network, ask and trust them to run them, then request that they send back via email the resulting output files. You should be able to retrieve the information from every one of your networked PCs without doing any of that. Do you not have a 'Tech' department or somebody who knows how to administrate a network? Also please be aware that it is very easy to spoof MAC addresses, so using them in a firewall does not really add much of a deterrent to an interested party.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to modify your batchfile into:

```
ipconfig /all > "%userprofile%\Desktop\UserIP.txt"
```

When you start up a commandline, you automatically are present in the `%userprofile%` directory, but most probably you did not store your batchfile there.